# How to process an uploaded csv file in python script using flask

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

How to process the file which is uploaded by giving the file path to the python script and download the processed file ?
**The code**

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP__ROOT, 'data/')
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        filename = file.filename
        print(filename)
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)
    return render_template("downloads.html")
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved this question? I also need to do this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the file.

```
response = app.make_response(file)
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=yourfile.csv"
return response
```

Comment: where to send this response i have a python script which takes path and dont where to save that as i was running it on terminal now i have to upload the file and process and then download